# is it posible to use the coca Dispatch Library?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am copying some code from objective C to Xamarin IOS which has a object of DispatchSemaphore but I can't it create it in C#.
Can I use DispatchSemaphore in Xamarin iOS or do I have to use C# threading ?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [dispatchgroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/corefoundation.dispatchgroup?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12).It can be used to manually manage dispatch group tasks by incrementing the current count of outstanding tasks in the group. by using the `Enter()` and `Leave()` methods.

```
DispatchGroup group = new DispatchGroup();

group.Enter();
 //your task1
group.Leave();

group.Enter();
 //your task2
group.Leave();
```

in C#,you could also look at [task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-5.0).